# Test suite fails when running all test cases at a time

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

I have a test suite with five(5) test cases. Each test case has a unique tag that represents test case number. If I run each test case one by one using the command,

```
robot -i <test-case-tag> <filename>.robot
```

each of them passed the test. But when I ran the all test cases at a time by just removing the `-i <test-case-tag>` in the previous command, only the first test case passed and the rest failed.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit with Python 2.7.13, Robot Framework 2.6.0, SeleniumLibrary 3.3.2 (versions based on pip install), and Mozilla Firefox 56.0. I also tried Google Chrome but same result.

Weird though I tried running it in Windows 10 using Firefox and Chrome and **most of the time** all five test cases passed (sometimes I still get only the first test case passed).

I don't know if this is a bug in Robot/Selenium or what.

Comment: Can you provide the encountered errors?

Comment: It all depends on why they failed. Robot and Selenium have no fundamental limitations like this, your tests must have something in them preventing them from being run together. Please show us the failure messages.

Comment: Do you open and close your browser in every test, or just once at the beginning/end?

Comment: @BrandonOlson In each test case the browser opens then closes.

Comment: @actc @Bryan Oakley The four test cases that failed has the same error message. `Invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated.` The error is referring to the first input field that my test executes. I don't know why it works on the first test case and does not after.

Comment: Guys, I think I already solved my problem. Do I need to state it here how or I just delete this post?

Comment: You can answer your question yourself, to share your knowledge with the community.